# how to hold the image size when src not exists?

Tags: html, image, placeholder, src

```
<img class="holder-image" src="" ng-click="onAvatarClick()">
```

like this, when the src not exists, I want to hold the size with a border or other images, what should I do ?

I fetch src of images from Internet, but some src doesnt work, it would show a small err image, I dont care what image is , I just want to keep the size designed.

Comment: add height & width attr to your tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following tag:

```
<img src="yourimageifany" id="imageid" />
```

Set CSS as follows:

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

You can get the image width as follows (using JQuery on load):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var width= $("#imageid").width(); //get width
    $('#imageid').height(width); //set height as width
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but I want to make width 100% and height = width, also, height value is not sure, but width should 100% appendding to her parent, without height px, it still a small block.

Comment: @ChenzhaoWudics Please check the updated code. Feel free to mark as answer, if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line:

```
<img class="holder-image" src="" ng-click="onAvatarClick()" height="200px" width="200px" />
```

This will set the height & width of your image as 200px

Comment: It works, but I want width to be 100% appendding to her parent, and the height should equal width ,  like a square.

Comment: try min-height=1px and width=100%

Comment: If you want both the values to be same, then either write javascript for the same or make container div as the same